# how long does it take to fill cistern (0.24 of cistern)?

Tags: calculation-puzzle

We have a cistern (reservoir). This storage has 2 income faucet (2 interval water) & 1 outgo faucet(1 out pass). By one of the interval pass which in bigger it takes 1 hour to fill storage & by smaller interval pass it takes 6 hours to fill storage.
And also it takes 7 hours to deplete storage from outgoing pass(faucet).
Now calculate in 0.24 hours how much of storage is filled (how much water is stored in storage?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understand properly what you're asking...

By one incoming faucet, a whole cisternworth of water comes in in 1 hour, so 0.24 of a cisternworth comes in in 0.24 hours. Similarly, by the other incoming faucet, a whole cisternworth comes in in 6 hours, so 0.24/6 = 0.04 comes in in 0.24 hours. And by the outgoing faucet, a whole cisternworth leaves in 7 hours, so 0.24/7 = 0.0342857... leaves in 0.24 hours. So the answer is 0.24 + 0.04 - 0.0342857... = 0.245714... = **43/175** of the cistern.